# Text Button showing as points instead of normal text

Tags: java, android, xml

Hey there i m looking for a solution for my current issue, it's weird the text of my buttons are points they don't show in strings example "Go" it shows as ".."
i m using the latest version of android studio
Picture of the result:
[image]

My XML CODE:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="508dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/egg" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="187dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="187dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="183dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="183dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timesLeft"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="81dp"
        android:text="00:30"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.473" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goButton"
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
        android:password="true"
        android:text="Go"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timesLeft" />
```

Comment: `android:password="true"`

Comment: remove this `android:password="true"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:password="true"` on the goButton should be unset or set to false